# Additional Statements after Case Causing Error

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a sql script I am writing and I have 2 statements in a select clause that are of the form:
`max(case when ... then ... end)`

I would like to add additional statements after these case statements but I get an error that says:

`Error at line 1
not a GROUP BY expression`

Here is my script:

```
create table mydb.test1 as
select distinct substr(testdb.wtags.FAO, 1) as Account_Number,
       max(Case
       when testdb.wtags.descriptor like 'Company for%' then ('CM' || substr(testdb.wtags.DESCRIPTOR, 18)) end ) Division,

       max(Case
       when testdb.wtags.value like 'CC%' then substr(testdb.wtags.value, 1) end) Department,

-------------------------------
           'CM' || substr(testdb.wtags.DESCRIPTOR, 18, 22) as Division,
           substr(testdb.wtags.value, 1, 10) as Department,
           substr(testdb.MASTERFILE.Workday_Description, 1, 20) as Description,
           '                    ' Responsible_Person,
           '                    ' Address,
           ' ' Delete_Flag,
           ' ' Freeze_Flag
-----------------------

  from testdb.wtags
       join testdb.masterfile 
           on testdb.wtags.fao = testdb.MASTERFILE.workday_number
           --where testdb.wtags.descriptor like 'Company for%'
           --OR testdb.wtags.value like 'CC%'
           --order by Account_Number Desc
           group by testdb.wtags.fao;
```

I would like to add the statements between the 2 dashed lines but that causes the error.
If I remove those statements, everything works.
I am using Toad for Oracle.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Allan - I get `not a GROUP BY expression` and then it highlights the first line of the script in red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with the `case` *expressions*, per se. It's that this is a query that's using `GROUP BY` - and so everything in the `SELECT` list needs to either be part of the `GROUP BY` clause or needs to be inside an aggregate function (e.g. `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, etc).

The columns you're attempting to reference fit neither of those conditions. I'm not going to make a recommendation which way things should be altered (add to `GROUP BY` or introduce an appropriate aggregate) since I have neither your data, nor even what you expect this query to produce as a result.

The error message could be more descriptive.

Comment: At this moment, I am not concerned with having the best performing code. I have experimented with commenting out the `group by` clause and I get a different error: `not a single-group group function` I am just trying to get the code to work.

Comment: @RXC - it's not about "having the best performing code" - you're telling the system to generate *one* row for each distinct `testdb.wtags.fao` value - and it doesn't know what to compute for these new columns you're adding because there could be *multiple* values of e.g. `testdb.wtags.value` for any particular `testdb.wtags.fao` value. Similarly, if you remove the `GROUP BY`, it now doesn't understand the `MAX()` calls in the select list because it's no longer reducing *multiple* rows down into a smaller number of rows.

Comment: ok, I got you. I wasn't too sure what the max was doing there in the first place but I get it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every field in the `SELECT` clause must be separated by a comma. There's no comma after `Department` (the alias for the second `case` statement).

---

When you're creating an aggregate query (one that has a `GROUP BY` clause), then every field in the `SELECT` clause must either be contained in an aggregate function (e.g. `max`, `min`, `avg`, etc.) or be included in the `GROUP BY` clause. It looks like you have several fields (`Descriptor`, `value`, `Workday_Description`) that violate this rule.

---

Just removing the `GROUP BY` clause doesn't work, because without it, you're not allowed to use aggregate functions (i.e. `max`).

Since we don't have your data or know what result you're trying to achieve, we can't tell you how to fix your query specifically. At best, we can tell you what your options are.

Comment: Sorry, I must have forgot to put that in there, but I do have a comma in my script and it still gives me the error. I will also update the psot.